# SSIS - OData Connection to Sharepoint List Failed Validation Error

Tags: ssis, odata

In SSIS (version 15, created through Visual Studio 2017), I am trying to connect to a Sharepoint list ("Deficiencies") with an HTTPS URL.  I get this error:

> Error: 0xC020801F at Deficiencies, Get Deficiencies Data [2]: Cannot
>   acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager.
>   Error: 0xC0047017 at Deficiencies, SSIS.Pipeline: Get Deficiencies
>   Data failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801F. Error:
>   0xC004700C at Deficiencies, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component
>   failed validation. Error: 0xC0024107 at Deficiencies: There were
>   errors during task validation.

I am using an OData Source.  The Connection Manager returns a "test successful" and previews the list data.  However, when I run the package in VS, it returns the above error.  It does the same whether I use Windows Authentication or use the service SQL account.

I'm including `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` at the end of the URL.